# Flutter firebase message: No message catch by iOS phone

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-ios

I am trying to use flutter firebase messaging on my application . I installed these libraries on **pubspec.yaml** file:

```
dependencies:
    ...
    firebase_core: ^0.5.1
    firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.9
```

In android I don't have any problem But in Ios I did not get any message even if my app been on foreground. In fact `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage` and `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` not triggered at all.

```
Future initialise() async {
    //Firebase.initializeApp() I initialized on main method first
    FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    _fcm.requestPermission(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      _token = await _fcm.getToken();
      print("------> token is: $_token");
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        _token = await _fcm.getAPNSToken(); // token received from firebase
        print("------> token is: $_token");

    }

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((remoteMessage) async {
      print('[onMessage] message: ${remoteMessage.data}');
      var msg = PushMsgModel().wrapOriginMessage(remoteMessage);
      _showOverlyNotify(msg);
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(onBackgroundMessage);
  }
```

- For IOS configuration I added

  ```
  <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
  <false/>
  ```

  in `Info.plist`.
- I created APNs certificate and I added into ios firebase project setting
- I registering an App Identifier
- I generating a provisioning profile and I added to `Provisioning Profile` in xcode.
- In Xcode, I selected Runner in the Project Navigator. In the
- Capabilities Tab I turned on Push Notifications and Background Modes,
  and enabled Background fetch and Remote notifications under Background Modes.
- I also did copy GoogleService-Info.plist file, in
  ios/Runner.xcworkspace with Xcode.

[image]

AppDelegate.swift includes:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

But I can't get any messages on android studio console when I push message from firebase console?
What is my mistake? Can someone help me?

When application can get token means my configuration is right?

I am testing on **iPhone7plus(mobile)** with software version 14.4

Comment: Add `import Firebase` & `FirebaseApp.configure()` in AppDelegate.swift

Comment: where i have to add `FirebaseApp.configure(` ! before `if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {`? @Priyesh

Comment: yes, just above `if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {` line

Comment: Nothing happen. print in onMessage.listen nothing printed.@Priyesh

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with IOS 15.2 on a real device with `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` while I had no issues with Android. I spent several days testing different suggestions, triple check my configuration, updating dependencies, testing custom APN payloads. Nothing worked.

For my case, I realised every time I do `flutter run` between my tests the application runs in debug mode takes a new `UUID` because app re-installation happens, as a result, the application couldn't map the notification that was arriving when the app had new UUID and the background handler was never triggered.

When I test it on release mode `flutter run --release` on a **real device** ensuring **UUID** remains the same (`iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor`) finally I got the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow heads-up notifications before your runApp().

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: false,
    badge: false,
    sound: false,
  );
```

Comment: `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen` wont called bro?setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions called before onMessage? @Rahul

Comment: Not working as I assumed. Because my message seems not arrived to app and `onMessage.listen` not triggered at all@Rahul

Comment: Can u try removing this?  
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }

Comment: Also, can u update the package and try? ^8.0.0-dev.11 or later

Comment: I update to  ^8.0.0-dev.14 but I also have sane problem @Rahul

Comment: Same problem. if we add registerForRemoteNotification in Appdelegate then logic for showing notification only for user which is logged in is lost.